# Tensorflow model street : using the LSTMCell to replace the lstm_layer function

Tags: tensorflow, lstm

I use LSTMCell in tensorflow to replace the lstm_layer function in nn_ops.py, but it seems working not so well.

Can anyone help me figure out what the problems.

Comment: Can you provide a complete sample code in order to reproduce your issue?

Comment: I made a wrong input to the rnn networks before, and I had solved the problem.